# Ordering by the count of another table?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a table called `user_room_vists` which store the visits to rooms each user makes. Here is the structure for this table and how I created it in my own database.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `user_room_visits`;
CREATE TABLE `user_room_visits` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `room_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `entry_timestamp` double NOT NULL,
  `exit_timestamp` double NOT NULL,
  `hour` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `minute` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  KEY `entry_timestamp` (`entry_timestamp`),
  KEY `exit_timestamp` (`exit_timestamp`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=73 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I then have a table called `users` which obviously holds the users. I'm trying to select (in order of the highest) the count of room visits a user has made.

This means I have to match the `user_id` column in `user_room_visits` with the `id` column in the `users` table, but because its in a seperate table it becomes complicated.

I haven't got any examples to show you of what I've tried because I'm stuck, every time I google this it comes up with something I can't put into terms of my own problem, that and the fact I just don't know what I need to do to achieve this. I also need to do this in the Laravel framework using its ORM Equolent, which makes querying a lot easier, so I need a bit more than just MySQL.

Here are the model files

```
class UserRoomVisit extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'user_room_visits';
    public $timestamps = true;
    protected $guarded = ['id'];
}

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    protected $table = 'users';
    public $timestamps = true;
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function userStats() {
        return $this->belongsTo(UserStats::class, 'id');
    }
}
```

Comment: What are the contents of Model files? Have you defined the relations there?

Comment: @UdayrajDeshmukh I've just updated my question with the model files.

Comment: @0b9ff4fb could you please explain what you want with some sample data?

Comment: I cant a collection of the `User` model ordered by the count of their room visits in `user_room_visits` in descending order, limited to 5.

Comment: Lets say the `users` table had a column called `room_visits`, I would do it like this: `User::orderBy('room_visits', 'DESC')->limit(5)->get();`, but it doesn't.. so I need to do something more complicated.

Comment: try to use `withCount()`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you don't want to use many-to-many relationship here. So, define the `userRoomVisits` relationship in the `Room` model:

```
public function userRoomVisits()
{
    return $this->hasMany(UserRoomVisit::class);
}
```

And use the [`withCount()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models) method like this to get rooms:

```
Room::withCount(['userRoomVisits' => function($q) {
        $q->where('user_id', auth()->id());
    }])
    ->latest('user_room_visits_count')
    ->get();
```

**Update**

The code for another question asked in the comments:

```
User::withCount('userRoomVisits')->latest('user_room_visits_count')->take(5)->get();
```

Define the relationship in the `User` model:

```
public function userRoomVisits()
{
    return $this->hasMany(UserRoomVisit::class);
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to get a collection of the `User` model, not the `Room` model.

Comment: @0b9ff4fb your original question is "I'm trying to select (in order of the highest) the count of room visits a user has made". But if you want to get users by `room_id` change the code. It's absolutely the same principle, the same relationship but defined in another model, the same code with exchanged relationships etc.

Comment: There's things wrong with your answer, firstly it doesn't put the collection in order of the count, secondly you've got an error in your code (near ->where, unexpected `->`) and lastly you aren't giving the relationship `hasMany` a column name.

Comment: I've fixed the second one, thanks. Also, I'm pretty sure it orders the rooms by count, I've used the code in many apps. And you also don't need to specify `hasMany` column name since you're [following Laravel model naming conventions](https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices#follow-laravel-naming-conventions) described in my repo.

Comment: When running your code I get an error `mb_strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given`, another issue is your passing `auth()->id()` when you should be passing the id of the current user model.

Comment: @0b9ff4fb updated the syntax. `auth()->id()` will return currently authenticated user ID.

Comment: I don't think you understand the question. I'm trying to get a collection of all the `User` models with the most populated data in table `user_room_visits`, not just the authenticated user. I need to do it for all users that exist in the DB and get the top 5, so that I can do something like `@foreach ($topRoomVisits as $user)` in my view. Your current code returns a single user.

Comment: @0b9ff4fb I understood the question. I've answered your original question which I've quoted in the second comment and I also told you to just swap relationships and models if you want to get users and not rooms. You could make an effort and understand how it works and modify the code by yourself.

Comment: @0b9ff4fb I've updated the answer with code for your another question.

Comment: Thank you, although how do I get the count of their room visits in the view? My current code (in view) is `@foreach ($topRoomVisits as $user)@endforeach`

Comment: @0b9ff4fb `{{ $user->user_room_visits_count }}` inside the loop you've shown.

Comment: @0b9ff4fb you should [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) if it helped you.